# Hyperapp, Social share link and og:url

Tags: facebook, hyperapp

I'm having a little problem with my (facebook) share link.
I use hyperapp and fbbot will not execute js, so my meta will not be displayed.

So i made a sharing page on my api (with a js redirect to my front for user).

Everything works good, but, when i share, i see [api-mydomain.com] in the preview/sharing post.

I understand that is my og:url that tell fb what to do.
So i need fb bot to stay on this api page to retrieve meta, but i would like [mydomain.com] in the post.

Is there a solution without php?

Am i doing it wrong way?
Thanks.

Comment: Facebook displays the domain to show users where the content they are viewing originates from; you can not “fake” that.

Comment: So my only solution is to put php controller on my front-end?

Comment: Pretty much, yeah. But don’t you have a server-side “fallback” in place already anyway? If someone _directly_ accesses a specific piece of content directly, by visiting a URL like `http://example.com/foo-bar`, surely your system must be handling that in some way already?

Comment: Nop, actually its for article/advice/recipe, that dont have specific page (except after sharing, the redirect is made on a public page) but the user cant create/get the url without using share button. Actually there is no php on front, only an index.html that initialize hyperapp.
(sorry if i missunderstood your reply, i'm french :s)